# Algorithm to solve y = sin(x) + x

Tags: algorithm, math

y = sin(x) + x

I know y and my goal is to find x.
Normally I'd write x as a function of y, but it doesn't work with this equation.
I'd rather not use Taylor series, so I'm trying to create a function to guess "x", calculate y with the equation, compare it with the correct y, then use the difference to "improve the next guess" and keep repeating the cycle until I find the correct x.
I was thinking of using a PID (i'm not even sure if it'd work), but I was wondering if there were simpler alternatives, any tips?

Comment: What wrong with Taylor? Seems like a reasonable choice with controlled precision.

Comment: because to have enough precision for what I'm doing I'd have to use 4-5 terms which would still be too much to solve. This equation is a simplified form of what I'm actually working on, I'm just trying to figure out the theory.

Comment: Bisection should work. Newton-Raphson should work (with certain precautions).

Comment: Bisection is a good choice because it's more nearly certain to work. Newton's method is fast if the starting guess is close enough; but "close enough" is a subtle question, it turns out, and detecting and working around "not close enough" would be a lot of additional complexity. The general topic is called numerical root finding; a web search will find a lot of resources.

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not seeing a use for Taylor series here. Replacing sin(x) with its Taylor series just means one now has to find the root of a polynomial, which is not really any easier than the original problem.

Comment: I didn't think of bisection, thank you guys I'll try that

Comment: Derivative is 1+cos(x), so non-negative for any x, one root, N-R or binary search should work

Comment: This sounds like a question for the Math site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have said, [Newton–Raphson iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is a good choice for this problem, and can solve for x with arbitrary accuracy:

1. Choose an initial value for x. Say, x = y.
2. Update x by computing

   ```
   x = x - (sin(x) + x - y) / (cos(x) + 1)
   ```
3. Repeat step 2 until convergence.

To decide when to stop, you can look at how much x is changing from one iteration to the next, or look at the residual magnitude |sin(x) + x - y|. Or, since the iteration converges fast, just perform a fixed number of iterations.

Example:

```
y = 1.234

———————————————————————————————————
Iteration            x   sin(x) + x
———————————————————————————————————
        1    0.5246103    1.0254861
        2    0.6363829    1.2306732
        3    0.6382268    1.2339990
        4    0.6382273    1.2340000
        5    0.6382273    1.2340000
———————————————————————————————————
```